# What's the "Spell Hint" is on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

I've no idea about what the system-wide "Spell Hint" exactly is, but, whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, I'll be prompted "spell hint is enabled | disabled".

Obviously, It's a toggle key for a spell hint app (or feature of some app).

**My problem is:** I used to set this short key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for my IntelliJ IDEA, but now it doesn't work. And I couldn't figure out which app has taken this hot key and I've no idea how to unset it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I met the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04. In my case, it seems to be related with my keyboard?/language? input method Fcitx (for Japanese input) rather than Ubuntu. So if you don't use Fcitx, my advice might not be useful. Or it might be a problem of Japanese keyboard/input.

You can find "Input Method Configuration" window by clicking a top-right keyboard icon.
In "Input Method tab" of the window, there will be list of your keyboard and input method.
Double-click your keyboard in the list, "Toggle the word hint" field uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then hit "Backspace" key, the value will turn "Empty", now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> as usual.

Comment: Great! But seems I cannot delete the "Ctrl+Alt+H" combination, when  I click "Backspace", Fcitx will use it as the new shortcut key, so I have to assign a complicate key instead. But anyway, you solve my problem! thanks!

Comment: @EvansY. Probably it's too late. Just a reference for other people who wanna know, one can empty the shortcut by "ESC".